# Firebase Read and Save Data Issues (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

A team and I are currently trying to connect our realtime firebase database to our swift/iOS XCode project. We are struggling to read the data that is in the current database and are hoping that somebody has an answer as to what our problem is.

```
refFoods = Database.database().reference().child("food");
        
refFoods.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { ( snapshot ) in
    // Get user value
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let foodName = value?["arborGrill/foodName"] as? String ?? "failed foodName"
    // let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
    //            let foodName = value?["foodName"] as? String ?? ""
    
    // print(value ?? "failed1")
    print(foodName)
    // ...

    
    // print(self.food)
  })
```

the database the code is supposed to pull from:
[image: the database the code is supposed to pull from]

We have tried to create a struct holding the values for foods:

```
struct Foods {
    var foodName:String
    var ratingAvg:Int
    var reviewStrings:Array = [""]
}
```

And tried to do workarounds such as Firestore to get this to work, but all to no avail. Does the database need to be formatted differently or is it an issue with our Swift code?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? Note that it's easiest to help if you stick to a single snippet, instead of sharing multiple snippets with variations you tried.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the problem is saving the values stored in 'let value' using swift.

Comment: So what does `print(foodName)` print? If you inspect `value` in the debugger, what's its value?

Comment: Plase dump(value) after let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary and see what you get I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help get you going.

It's a good idea to leave data within DataSnapshots as long as possible - e.g. converting to Dictionary can make it more complex to deal with.

Also, ordering can be important so as you can see the first step is taking the child nodes and casting them to an array to preserve order

.observeSingleEvent is being used here as I am only reading the foods once, without leaving an observer of future changes.

```
func readAllFoods() {
    let ref = self.ref.child("foods") //self.ref points to MY firebase.
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allRestaurantsSnap = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] //contains all child nodes of food
        for foodSnap in allRestaurantsSnap { //iterate over each restaurant node
            let restaurantName = foodSnap.key //arborGrill, burgerKing etc
            let foodName = foodSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "foodName").value as? String ?? "No food name"
            print(foodName)
        }
    })
}
```

I will also dissuade you from using an array in NoSQL databases. They can be very limiting and are difficult to work with as if you need to change the array, it has to be read in, changed, deleted, and written back out.

So instead of this

```
reviewString
  0: Some Review
  1: Another Review
```

do this

```
reviews
   -9as99idjk4ii9jas09 //created with childByAutoId
      review: "Awesome restaurant"
      by_user: "uid_1234"
      date: 20210131
   -ajsijo9fj9dkkfg00d
      review: "Top notch cuizine"
      by_user: "uid_5678"
      date: 20210210
```

etc

Comment: Thank you so much! This managed to do the trick.